# how to use Hashmap to filter data in multithreading to serve multiple clients

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

Sample data store in hashmap is as ,

e.g.
{"client1-data1":data1,"client2-data2":data2,"client3-data3":data3,"client4-data4":data4,"client1-data2":data2,"client2-data1":data1,"client3-data4":data4,"client4-data3":data3}

every data can be get repeated for every other client , the key will be unique as client1-data1 combination value will get repeated but key will be unique.

Issue for handling multiple clients,

for every user , a different thread is created while making a connection so every thread will created a PrintWriter object which gets added to a Arraylist

List writers = new ArrayList();

Is their anyways where i can store the client_id along with the Printwriter object in the same array and pass the data to clients while filter the data with that client id as stored in the Hashmap in the above example.

PLease do reply/suggest

thanks,
Praveen T

Comment: 1. *every data can be get repeated for every other client , the key will be unique as client1-data1 combination value will get repeated but key will be unique.* - I didn't understand this.

Comment: 2. *for every user , a different thread is created* - 'user' == 'client'?

Comment: 3. Is this java? If you choose to edit your answer, do include the [java] tag.

Comment: @ArjunShankar yes user==client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a collection which stores a pair of elements. A round about way of doing this is to use a Map.

```
Map<PrintWriter, String> writeAndClientId = new HashMap<>();
```

You can loop over these using

```
for(Map.Entry<PrintWriter, String> entry: writeAndClientId.entrySet())
```

---

If you want to be able to get one clientId at a time you can use

```
Map<String, PrintWriter> clientIdToWriter = new HashMap<>();

PrintWriter pw = clientIdToWriter.get(clientId);
```

Comment: here im sending the data by looping the arraylist so how could i access the client/user to filter the data.                          for(int i=0; i<writers.size();i++)
{
 broad=writers.get(i);
 broad.println(data);
} the way i access the writers from the arraylist how could i access the same in case of Hashmap both i.e (Printwriter Object) and client ID.

Comment: You would loop over the entrySet()

Comment: Thanks @peter for ur prompt reply but just one more thing how will i write the data for particular printwriter object in loop and how to compare the client id string is it like this, for comparing with client id entry.getValue()==clientString; and for writing to the PrintWriter object PrintWrite pw = entry.getKey(); pw.println(data); will this work

Comment: If you want just one clientId at a time you can invert the map and use a get.

Comment: im new to the collections can i know how exactly invert works to get a single clientid ata time

Answer (score 0):

Printers and Clients are unique, so take a Set(no duplicate Id) or HashMap and manage something like this :

```
final HashMap<Writer, HashMap<Integer, List<String>>> writers = new HashMap<Writer, HashMap<Integer, List<String>>>();
```

Let us know if I've misunderstood  something.